# Securing Spring Boot Web App With Spring Security Doesn't Work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've spent about a full day attempting to get a very basic Spring Boot app with Spring security up and running to no avail. I cannot find a single example of code that works when I run it.

[This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) example is from spring.io. Here is what I'm seeing in that example:

1. I start at http://localhost:8080 and see the welcome screen.
2. I click a link to http://localhost:8080/hello, which redirects me to http://localhost:8080/login.
3. I enter "user" and "password" as specified in WebSecurityConfig.java, which redirects me back to the welcome screen. I was expecting to be redirected to http://localhost:8080/hello.
4. When I click the same link to http://localhost:8080/hello I get the login screen again.

I've tried debugging via @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) but there are no errors.

The above experience is endemic of what I experience when I download every example. Admittedly I'm new to Spring, and presumably I'm making some kind of newbie configuration mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the code and ran using maven and it works perfectly fine. After logging in, for all subsequent page loads of `http://localhost:8080/hello` loads the page and not the login page again unless of course I log out. The problem you have mentioned may be caused by ( with quite high probability since you have mentioned it's endemic) is that your browser may be having issue with transmitting the default JSESSIONID cookie (which is set on first page visit and updated ( as good security practise by Spring security) on first login. For subsequent visits same JSESSIONID is sent to the server and it is a key for the session object stored on server which contains the now authenticated/authorized user. If some how this cookie is not transmitted back to server ( one reason could be it's disabled in browser setting) then your application (protected by spring security) would not know that you are an already authenticated user and will show you the login page again. For e.g, for Chrome you can see the cookie settings at Settings --> Content Settings --> Cookies --> Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended). You can also view the cookie header getting passed on each page load post successful login by using Developer tool in respective browser.